Как запустить Jquery Sortable на событии touchstart?
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.14.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <style>
        #sortable {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 60%;
        }

        #sortable li {
            margin: 0 3px 3px 3px;
            padding: 0.4em;
            padding-left: 1.5em;
            font-size: 1.4em;
            height: 18px;
        }

        #sortable li span {
            position: absolute;
            margin-left: -1.3em;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.14.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#sortable").sortable();

            $("#sortable").sortable( "disable" );
        });

        $("#sortable").on("contextmenu", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        })

        $("#sortable").on("touchstart", () => {
            $("#sortable").sortable( "enable" );
        })
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <ul id="sortable">
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 6</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 7</li>
    </ul>

</body>

</html>

Методы которые указаны не работают. Работает если только отпустить палец и снова нажать. Но нужно при первом касании.

Это SO на русском. Переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык

Да спс, что то по привычке забыл
